# copy certain files using batch script with whitelist txt file

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have an issue in copying a certain files to another folder using whitelisting text file

in folder1 , i have 1.txt , 2.txt , 3.txt 
I need to copy oni 1.txt and 3.txt into folder2

in my whitelist.txt , I have a "c:\folder1\1.txt" and "c:\folder1\3.txt"

How do I use batch script to do a copy on this issue?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
  setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
  for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%f in ("c:\wherever\whitelist.txt") do (
    copy "%%~f" "c:\folder2"
  )
```

For each line in the indicated file, read the line into variable `%%f` (your file), and execute a copy of the indicated file to folder2 (`%%~f` is the content of the variable unquoted, as we are adding the quotes)

EDITED - From comments: The `whitelist.txt` contains files *not* to be copied.

If the "whitelist" does not include the path the solution is easy, just get the list of files in the folder and check against the "whitelist" for elements not matching

```
@echo off
set "from=d:\folder1"
set "to=c:\folder2"
set "whitelist=c:\somewhere\whitelist.txt"

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'dir /b /a-d "%from%\*" ^| findstr /l /x /v /g:"%whitelist%"'
) do (
    echo copy "%from%\%%~f" "%to%"
)
```

But as indicated, whitelist contains the paths of the files. And dir command does not include the path unless `/s` is used, but it has not been indicated a recursive copy, so, it will be necessary to generate the list of files with path

```
@echo off

set "from=d:\folder1"
set "to=c:\folder2"
set "whitelist=c:\somewhere\whitelist.txt"

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'cmd /q /c "for %%x in (""%from%\*"") do (echo(%%~fx)" ^| findstr /l /x /v /g:"%whitelist%"'
) do (
    echo copy "%%~f" "%to%"
)
```

Comment: Hi sorry to ask again. what if I just gonna copy 2.txt instead of 1.txt and 3.txt ? my mistakes =(

Comment: @user3145735: then, is the key file a white list of files to be copied or a black list of files not to be copied? If it is a whitelist, just include in it anything you want copied. If it is a black list, then code needs to be changed.

Comment: the whitelist.txt contain the files that need not be copied, the files that are not listed should be copied.